# alert in javascript not working

Tags: javascript

guys i am sure the answer will be trivial, but i've been staring at my code for hours now and am just not able to figure out why my alerts aren't triggering.....help please!
None of the alerts seem to be triggering

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script>
            window.onload=function()
            {
                setTimeout(loadImg("img1.jpg",0),500);
                setTimeout(loadImg("img2.jpg",1),1500);
                setTimeout(loadImg("img3.jpg",2),3000);
                setTimeout(loadImg("img4.jpg",3),5000);
                setTimeout(loadImg("img5.jpg",4),4000);
            }

            function loadImg(loc,num)
            {
                alert("in loadImg");
                function load()
                {
                    img=document.getElementByTagName("img");
                    img[num].src=loc;
                }
                return load;
            }

            function search()
            {
                alert("in search");
                isbn=document.getElementById("isbn").value;
                xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET","http://localhost/lab6x/serverx.php?isbn=+"isbn,true);
                xhr.onreadystatechande=function()
                {
                    alert("in handler");
                    if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
                    {
                        p=document.getElementById("book");
                        p.innerHTML=xhr.responseText();
                    }
                }
                xhr.send(null);
            }


        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="loader.gif" height="200px" width="200px"></img>
        <img height="200px" width="200px"></img>
        <img height="200px" width="200px"></img>
        <img height="200px" width="200px"></img>
        <img height="200px" width="200px"></img>

            <div>
                </br>
                ISBN:<input type="text" id="isbn"/>
                <button onclick="search()">SEARCH</button>

                <p id="book"></p></br>
            </div>
            <p> akhfjkahsjhajkhfhfadkhfahfjkshdfjkshdfkhdfshfkshdf</br>
            jhjkhfjhsjkdfhjkdhfjkshfjksfjkhsjdkfhjk</br></p>

            <a href="https://www.google.com">google</p>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: getElementByTagName should be ...Elements...  A good option for you will be jshint to check your files, http://www.jshint.com

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in this line, so the code won't run at all:

```
xhr.open("GET","http://localhost/lab6x/serverx.php?isbn=+"isbn,true);
```

You have put the `+` inside the string instead of between the strings:

```
xhr.open("GET","http://localhost/lab6x/serverx.php?isbn=" + isbn,true);
```

---

Other problems in the code:

- Your doctype tag is malformed, it should be: `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
- The `getElementByTagName` call should be `getElementsByTagName`.
- There is no ending tags for `img` tags.
- You are using CSS units in the HTML attributes for size: `height="200" width="200"`.
- Your break tags are malformed: `<br>` or `<br />`.

Comment: @MrMartiniMo: Why did you try to edit out part of the answer?

Answer (score 1):

you have two small issues in your code.

Line 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Line 31:

```
xhr.open("GET","http://localhost/lab6x/serverx.php?isbn=" + isbn,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the alerts are trigerring, I sugegst you rewrite your setTimeouts. setTimeout and setInterval are rather picky sometimes. try this instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){loadImg("img1.jpg",0)},500);
```

And so on. Basically encapsule the loadImg call in a function.

Also, do what the others said :)

Comment: Wrapping the functions like that would keep the code that changes the images from running at all. The `loadImg` function returns a function that has to be executed.